# What are the elements in $A \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[q,q^{-1}]} \mathbb{C}(q)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a right $\mathbb{C}[q,q^{-1}]$-module. What are the elements in $A \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[q,q^{-1} \ ]} \mathbb{C}(q)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Tensors (most of them are). Seriously, anything more concrete about $A$?

Comment: @darij grinberg, thank you very much. For example, $A$ is $\overline{S_q(V)}$ in (3) of Definition 2 on page 6 (the 4-th page of the pdf file) of [the paper](http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=RLIN_1999_9_10_1_5_0).

Comment: Definition 2 (2) claims that $\overline{S_q\left(V\right)}$ is free as a graded $\mathbb C\left[q,q^{-1}\right]$-module. So I'd regard the tensor product as a base change to $\mathbb C\left(q\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a $\mathbb{C}[q, q^{-1}]$-module $\mathbb{C}(q)$ has a basis $\{\frac{1}{p}\}$ where $p$ is a polynomial with nonzero constant term. So that $A\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[q, q^{-1}]}\mathbb{C}(q)=\bigoplus_p A$. More explicitly, this says elements are sums of elements of the form $\frac{a}{p}$ where $p$ is complex polynomial with nonconstant term, and $a\in A$.